# Is Cronbach's alpha a parametric or non-parametric test?

Tags: nonparametric, cronbachs-alpha

Is Cronbach's alpha a parametric or non-parametric test? I need to know more specific details about it.

Comment: Welcome to our site! At the moment it is somewhat unclear what you are asking - could you explain what you mean by " I need to know more specific details about it"? What in particular do you need to know? I'm also a little confused by the reference to a hypothesis test. Could you explain what hypothesis you are seeking to test?

Comment: Although this question proceeds from false premises, it can be answered. (Ie, those misunderstandings can be cleared up.) This doesn't need to be closed, IMO.

Answer (score 1):

[Chronbach's alpha](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cronbach%27s_alpha) is not a test at all, it's a *measure* of reliability of test scores, looking at (in a particular sense) their *internal consistency*.

It is responsive to the correlation between items -- as the items become more highly correlated, Chronbach's alpha will generally increase.

Sometimes people may require that Chronbach's alpha achieve some arbitrary minimum threshold value, but that's not a test in the statistical sense.

Comment: All thanks to clarify the point, what is the value at which the value of Chronbach's alpha is acceptable, I found the values 0.6 and 0.7 are used as the threshold to accept it. and What is the scientific justification for the selection of the threshold value at which we are accepted.

Comment: @MohamedLoayDahhan What is okay depends on who you ask! The linked Wikipedia article discusses thresholds in more detail than I could (giving several criteria), but in any case an in depth discussion of what would make it acceptable lies outside the statistical issues, and I don't really think arbitrary cut offs on it have all that much to do with science either. Just naming a precise threshold to blindly apply in every situation may be comforting (or perhaps disconcerting) but not necessarily scientifically relevant -- in some situations it may be more like astrology than it is like astronomy